# kubernetes v1.17.3 sonobuoy e2e test failed for AdmissionWebhook

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks, e2e-testing

**environment**

```
[root@master01 ~]# kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.17.3
Server Version: v1.17.3

[root@master01 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
```

**what i do**

install kubernetes v1.17.3 with kubeadm,then run:

```
sonobuoy run --wait
```

**what happend**

e2e test failed:

```
[root@master01 ~]# sonobuoy results $results
Plugin: e2e
Status: failed
Total: 4843
Passed: 258
Failed: 20
Skipped: 4565

Failed tests:
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should honor timeout [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should mutate custom resource with different stored version [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should mutate pod and apply defaults after mutation [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should deny crd creation [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should unconditionally reject operations on fail closed webhook [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should be able to deny custom resource creation, update and deletion [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should be able to deny attaching pod [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] CustomResourceConversionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should be able to convert a non homogeneous list of CRs [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] patching/updating a mutating webhook should work [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should not be able to mutate or prevent deletion of webhook configuration objects [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] CustomResourceConversionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should be able to convert from CR v1 to CR v2 [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should mutate custom resource with pruning [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should be able to deny pod and configmap creation [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should mutate custom resource [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] listing mutating webhooks should work [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] CustomResourcePublishOpenAPI [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] updates the published spec when one version gets renamed [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] patching/updating a validating webhook should work [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] Aggregator Should be able to support the 1.10 Sample API Server using the current Aggregator [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] listing validating webhooks should work [Conformance]
[sig-api-machinery] AdmissionWebhook [Privileged:ClusterAdmin] should mutate configmap [Conformance]

Plugin: systemd-logs
Status: passed
Total: 5
Passed: 5
Failed: 0
Skipped: 0
```

**e2e.log as follow link:**

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/willzhang/9b11a8b4fa216e6eb5bc6a5b4bfbe83a/raw/37433fd8708a7c0d56b46e8f489432ec769406f5/v1.17.3-e2e.log

Comment: The exact question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change flannel to calico, then test success!